# angular material responsive grid layout on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a 4 x 2 column grid on large screens, looks good. I'm trying to make it when it goes to tablet size, then make the grid 3 x 2 and on mobile 2 x 4.

I played around with `flex-sm` but couldn't seem to figure out how to push things around.

If this helps, the end results I'm trying to get is a horizontal scroll of cards. Large screens will have 4 columns, tablets will have 3 columns, and mobile will have 2 columns. Then the user can scroll left and right to load more and see other columns.

Here is the code i'm working with

```
        <div flex layout="column" layout-margin>
            <md-content>
                <div layout="row">
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div layout="row">
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </div>
```

**Edit**:

looks like `layout-wrap` and or `mdGridList API` might be my solution. but i'm having trouble getting a default amount of rows at start. example, i moved everything to one row and added `layout-wrap` but the effect i get on desktop is card1 card2 card3 card4 card5, second row (wrapped elements) card 6, blank, card 7, blank, card 8.

```
        <div flex layout="column" layout-margin>
            <md-content>
                <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" flex="auto"></div>
                    <div flex="25" flex-md="33" flex-sm="45" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
                        <md-card></md-card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </div>
```

Comment: Its been long but did you get any solution to this?